# Is it normal to get several badges at the same time and rep in multiples?

Tags: discussion

I was looking around a bit and stumbled on something I found really strange...

First thing that prompted my curiosity was seeing a certain user who obtained the badge "Enlightened" several times in a row within a short time span of 1 minute:

[image]

Looking around some other badges ("Nice Answer", "Good Answer", "Great Answer"), there seemed to be some more of the same thing. Well, no more about badges (you can see a bit of them on the activity page under badges), let's move on.

Onto the user's page, all the rep are in multiple of 3:

[image]

I mean, don't you just find it strange? Even the downvotes are in multiple of 3 and at exactly the same time. Could it be a bug or is it really that easy to stack up so many badges in a row. If so, I'd like to know the secret ;)

NOTE:

- I hope it's okay if I don't blur the username. I don't want to bring the user negative attention, but it just jumped out to me.
- I'm not sure what to tag, so I'm using the discussion tag for now, since I'm not even sure what's happening here.

Comment: It's rather likely that it's sock puppeting.  Just flag a post, say that you suspect the user is creating account to vote for themself (or just say sock puppeting) and a mod will look into it.

Comment: The user was merged, so all of their badges were re-awarded to the new account.

Comment: @animuson Ah, that could explain these. By the looks of it, it looks like 3 users were merged into a single account? And all the three users have been getting rep the same time?

Comment: @Servy I guess I could do that as well. It's the first time I see this sort of thing. I will do so next time, though for now, I guess it's a bit late ^^; Thanks!

Comment: @animuson Any idea on the rep part? I know you marked the question as dup, but it's not fully so, yes? Unless the merging also explains the rep pattern.

Comment: This was a problematic merge. We're looking into it.

Comment: @AnnaLear Thank you :)

Comment: Two things happened: 1. I screwed up the merge, so there was all sorts of reputation history weirdness. 2. The merge process picked the newer user out of the two profiles to be the "master", so all badges and whatnot effectively got re-awarded. Fun times all around!